# How to install libx265 for ffmpeg on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, libx265

I have tried multiple guides [here](https://hexeract.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/how-to-compile-ffmpegmplayer-for-macosx/) (search for "Building libx265") and [here](http://sinclairmediatech.com/building-ffmpeg-with-libx265/) with no success.  Both times I made sure I uninstalled ffmpeg first, went through the guides, then ran

`brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-freetype --with-libass --with-libvpx --enable-libx265`

No matter what when I go to run a command like

`ffmpeg -i source.mkv -c:v libx265 test1.mkv`

I get the error:

`Unknown encoder 'libx265'`

Has anyone had success building libx265 for use with ffmpeg on OSX and can you please share how you did it?

P.S. I am running OSX 10.11.3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using `--with-x265` instead of `--enable-libx265` as described in the official FFmpeg wiki. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX

Those guides you linked to are not specifically for homebrew, which is why they used `--enable` instead of `--with`.

Comment: Bah, of course it would be that simple.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I had the exact same issue a while back when learning to use homebrew.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, see Jack's answer below.

Answer (score 25):

Seems like you can't just do `brew install ffmpeg --with-x265` anymore (this is Oct 2019). What worked for me is this:

```
brew tap homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg
brew install homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg
```

This is from https://github.com/homebrew-ffmpeg/homebrew-ffmpeg. It says the default already includes x265, but you can then optionally pass some arguments like

```
brew install homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg --with-xvid --with-fdk-aac
```

You can take a look at what options are available by doing

```
brew options homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg
```

Comment: Thank you! As of 12/4/19, option flags still don't seem to be working with standard `brew install ffmpeg`