# libx265 now calls an outdated version of ffmpeg

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I referenced this existing posting to get started: [How to install libx265 for ffmpeg on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118658/how-to-install-libx265-for-ffmpeg-on-mac-osx/36118763#36118763?newreg=b597157ee4a54ecebbae9f66196a17a8)

Now that I have uninstalled ffmpeg with "brew uninstall --force ffmpeg" and installed with the corrected version listed in the link above, I am getting the error message: bash: /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/bin/ffmpeg: No such file or directory.

The issue is easily located due to /ffmpeg/3.0.2 not existing.  The only existing directory at that location is 3.2.2, and the corresponding bin/ffmpeg inside of it.

It is helpful to note that I had previously gotten ffmpeg doing what I needed it to by following this installation guide, and my issues arose only when trying to enable and use h265 encoding following the steps in the above linked posting: http://www.renevolution.com/ffmpeg/2013/03/16/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x.html

The last step in the above-linked renevolution post installs more libraries - perhaps there is some dependency I'm missing?  I have attempted reinstalling and following the renevolution post to get back to my baseline testing, but am still getting the same 'version' error.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.  I am very new at this and trying to solve a problem a bit over my head.

Comment: I have now been able to regress and run my original conversions, but am now running into the same issue as Spencer in the linked article where it states "Unknown encoder 'libx265".  The brew installation is telling me it's already installed, and "brew info ffmpeg" lists x265 as an available option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **homebrew**, you should ensure that your PATH is set correctly and that `/usr/local/bin` is at the very start of your PATH because that is where **homebrew** installs all its binaries/executables.

So, make sure you have something like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

in your `bash` login file - `$HOME/.profile` or similar and that when you log out and back in again and run:

```
echo $PATH
```

that `/usr/local/bin` is really at the start of it.

Then delete `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` with:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

and then reinstall it with:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Then, hopefully, you will be in a good place!

Comment: Thank you!  This appears to have worked for me!  Now to figure out how to do what I need to....